# Objective-C object into C Callback function

Tags: objective-c, c, callback

The target: to use patterns images to draw in Quartz 2D. At the present moment:

```
const CGPatternCallbacks kPatternCallbacks = {0, routine, NULL};

void routine(void *info, CGContextRef contextRef) {

    UIImage *brushTexture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PatternImage1"];

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), brushTexture.CGImage);
}
```

To use in:

```
    CGPatternRef strokePattern = CGPatternCreate(NULL,
                                                 CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50),
                                                 CGAffineTransformIdentity,
                                                 50, // horizontal spacing
                                                 50, // vertical spacing
                                                 kCGPatternTilingNoDistortion,
                                                 true,
                                                 &kPatternCallbacks);
```

All this stuff inside implementation class (ViewController.m). And perfect, I can draw a pattern image.

The problem: to change something inside C callback function dynamically, in example:

In "ViewController.h"

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSString *imageName;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *imageName;
```

And in the implementation class (ViewController.m)

```
@synthesize imageName;

imageName = @"PatternImage1";

void routine(void *info, CGContextRef contextRef) {

    //UIImage *brushTexture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PatternImage1"];

    //CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), brushTexture.CGImage);
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), imageName.CGImage);
}
```

**And ERROR!!! -> Use of undeclared identifier 'imageName'**

And I've already tried...

```
void routine(void *info, CGContextRef contextRef) {

    //NSString *imageName = CFBridgingRelease(info);     //<- not working

    //NSString *imageName = (__bridge NSString *)(info);  //<- not working

    NSString *imageName = (__bridge NSString *) info;     //<- not working


    //UIImage *brushTexture = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PatternImage1"];

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), imageName.CGImage);
}
```

The routine structure can not change because it is defined by CGPatternCallbacks.

```
void routine(void *info, CGContextRef contextRef) { }
```

I searched a lot but have not found the solution. Topics like:

- "Pass an Objective-C object to C function"
- "Mix Objective-C and C"
- "Callback function"
- "C Callbacks"

Nothing, nothing and nothing.

Impossible? I do not think so! I will have to abandon... F***!

Comment: You are trying to access an instance variable of your class from a C function - that's not possible. Just a suggestion - use a global variable and set it to point to your view controller before invoking `CGPatternCreate`. That way you'll be able to access the property in the callback (ex. - `controller.imageName.CGImage`).

Comment: Thank you. I found it. I used the sentence:  -> static NSString *imageName = @"PatternImage1";  <-   And now, I can change the pattern image dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found it !!!**

**Found iiiiiiiit !!!**

```
static NSString *imageName = @"PatternImage1";
```

**It is visible inside callback function !!!!**

**Yabba Dabba Doo !!!**

Complete source code. Only in "ViewController.m" :

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

static NSString *imageName = @"PatternImage1";
```

In some part of code:

```
const CGPatternCallbacks kPatternCallbacks = {0, routine, NULL};
```

In some part of code:

```
CGPatternRef strokePattern = CGPatternCreate(NULL, CGRectMake(0,0,50,50),
                                                 CGAffineTransformIdentity,
                                                 50, 50,
                                                 kCGPatternTilingNoDistortion,
                                                 true,
                                                 &kPatternCallbacks);
```

In some part of code, an "if/else" statement:

```
if () {
  imageName = @"PatternImage2";

} else if () {
  imageName = @"PatternImage3";

} else {
  imageName = @"PatternImage4";
}
```

And finally, the callback function:

```
void routine(void *info, CGContextRef contextRef) {

    UIImage *brushTexture = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];

    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), brushTexture.CGImage);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `info` parameter the gets passed to your callback is whatever value you passed as the `info` parameter in your call to `CGPatternCreate()`. In Objective-C code, you would typically pass `(__bridge void*)self`. Then, in your callback, you'd cast it back to the appropriate type and call a method to do the real work:

```
void routine(void *info, CGContextRef contextRef) {
    ViewController* self = (__bridge ViewController*)info;
    [self drawPattern:contextRef];
}

- (void) drawPattern:(CGContextRef)contextRef {
    UIImage *brushTexture = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName]; // <- imageName can be an ivar
    CGContextDrawImage(contextRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50), brushTexture.CGImage);
}
```

In your very simple case where you just want to pass an image name string in, you could pass that `NSString*` as the `info` pointer, instead. Or even the `UIImage*` created from the name so you don't have to create it each time. That avoids the need to call a method on the recovered `self`. However, it is very common to have more complicated needs, even if your needs right now are simple, so it's often worth the trouble to pass in `self`.

Comment: I appreciate your comments very much. I did not know the syntax to call a method in Objective-C "- (void)" inside Callback Function, and could not find it searching forums. I will use your proposal to avoid creating NSObjects repeatedly in each function call. Because of course, my project makes more operations, such as changing the colour of the pattern.

Comment: Sorry, but I tried the alternative you propose, but does NOT WORK. Now I can not draw using the selected pattern image.

Comment: I made a copy/paste of the code. But it is possible that my application has some peculiarity: perhaps this fact alter the result. My App is an application to draw (with Quartz2D) and I use the method: - (void) touchesMoved.